# Repair on a 3-node Cassandra cluster returns error "Got negative replies from endpoints"

Tags: cassandra

I have a 3 node cluster that is running as side-car in K8.  One of the node went down and there was data update while it was down.

I tried to run repair, `nodetool repair sourcekeyspace priceconfig` to repair the table, but get an error.

I tried to run repair on all 3 servers and all of them are giving error.

What can I do to fix the problem?

**NODE 1**

```
itemdisplaytypename | sizebucket | pricetier | dbdateupdated                   | ruleid                               
        Matte Photo |      GIANT |      BEST | 2022-08-14 09:26:24.822000+0000 | e4b2ec36-b031-4361-8399-a9bdc949c860
```

**NODE 3**

```
itemdisplaytypename | sizebucket | pricetier | dbdateupdated | ruleid 
        Matte Photo |      GIANT |      BEST |          null |   null
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
-- > NODE 1
[2022-09-01 00:57:32,093] Repair command #3 failed with error Got negative replies from endpoints [xx.xx.3.84]
[2022-09-01 00:57:32,093] Repair command #3 finished with error
error: Repair job has failed with the error message: [2022-09-01 00:57:32,093] Repair command #3 failed with error Got negative replies from endpoints [xx.xx.3.84]

--> NODE 2
[2022-09-01 01:01:17,887] Repair command #2 failed with error Got negative replies from endpoints [xx.xx.3.84]
[2022-09-01 01:01:17,887] Repair command #2 finished with error
error: Repair job has failed with the error message: [2022-09-01 01:01:17,887] Repair command #2 failed with error Got negative replies from endpoints [xx.xx.3.84]

 --> NODE 3
[2022-09-01 01:02:53,575] Repair command #8 failed with error Got negative replies from endpoints [xx.xx.1.72, xx.xx.2.167]
[2022-09-01 01:02:53,575] Repair command #8 finished with error
```

Answer (score 2):

This repair error:

```
Got negative replies from endpoints [...]
```

is quite serious. Not only did the repair command *not* receive an error from one of the replicas (endpoints) -- it didn't get a response at all which indicates that the node is either down or unresponsive.

The most common cause (but not always) of this repair failure is a schema disagreement, i.e. the schema do not match across all nodes. This can happen if someone made a schema change while the node was down.

Ultimately, you will need to review the logs on the problematic endpoint(s) to determine the cause of the problem. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Erick,

You are correct that there was a node down when the schema was change.  However, the schema is the same now across the 3 nodes, but the data is not.

All the 3 nodes are up at the moment. That is when I tried to repair with data inconsistency with "nodetool repair", but is failing when I tried to run on it on each node.

The challenge is how do I rectify the inconsistent data?

Regards,
Tommy

Comment: Like I said, you need to review the logs on the problematic nodes to figure out what's going on. Cheers!